# name coin applicability to RDF data model URI specification

Tags: namecoin, database

In the [RDF data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) things are named with URIs which are essentially just URLs with more precise information appended to them. See here:

```
@prefix eric:    <http://www.w3.org/People/EM/contact#> .
@prefix contact: <http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/contact#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

eric:me contact:fullName "Eric Miller" .
eric:me contact:mailbox <mailto:e.miller123(at)example> .
eric:me contact:personalTitle "Dr." .
eric:me rdf:type contact:Person .
```

Is there any concivable utility in naming entities in RDF using Namecoin?

Maybe immutability? Since DNS hosted domains are subject to disappear over time for whatever reason. As in an [NYT article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/09/24/us/politics/in-supreme-court-opinions-clicks-that-lead-nowhere.html) I read that 50% of the links in US supreme court cases are now defunct.

Though I know that really things in Namecoin are not really immutable, they are also subject to change/transferance but maybe they're more persistent than centralized DNS IP system.